# Locating a Custom Action in SharePoint 2007

Tags: 2007, migration, custom-action

I am working on upgrading an old MOSS application, and among other things it contains a custom action clearly visible in one of the libraries. I have set up a new CustomAction element in my new farm solution but we're not sure what was the Rights mask on the original action.

My problem is that I cannot find the definition in MOSS. I looked everywhere I could think of in the FEATURES folder there is no trace of that action in any XML document, there is no DLL, and the OOTB SiteActions.xml files are not modified.

So I ask thee, SharePoint SE community, for help. It's 10pm, do you know where my MOSS CustomActions are?

Comment: If you are talking about finding the location of the custom action in a browser can't you just use element inspector to see it's location or id?

Comment: I was trying to find the definition of the custom action, not it's ID. We found it, see answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, we finally found it. It was added directly through JavaScript embedded in the view (hello best practices!), not through XML or code and that's why I couldn't find it.

You can add actions into the Item Menu through JavaScript with the following SharePoint functions (available 2007 through 2013):

```
CAMOpt(m, actionLabel, navigateUrl, iconPath);
```

And to add a separator:

```
CAMSep(m);
```

These functions should be called inside one of the hooks available in JavaScript (which will also provide the menu and context):

```
Custom_AddListMenuItems(m, ctx);
Custom_AddDocLibMenuItems(m, ctx);
AddCheckinCheckoutMenuItem(m, ctx, url);
```

Further references:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd587215(v=office.11).aspx
http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/customizing-the-sharepoint-ecb-with-javascript-part-2